# Determine the domain, codomain and image of a linear map

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> Let $$A= \begin{bmatrix} 1 && 0 && 2 && 0 \\ 0 && 3 && 0 && 5 \\ 5 && 0 &&0 && -6 \end{bmatrix}$$ determine the domain, codomain and image of the linear map $L$ corresponding to $A$.

From $T(x) = Ax$ I get that $$\begin{bmatrix} 1 && 0 && 2 && 0 \\ 0 && 3 && 0 && 5 \\ 5 && 0 &&0 && -6 \end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix} x \\y\\z\\w \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} x+2z+6w \\3y+5w \\5x-6w \end{bmatrix}$$

So $T(x,y,z,w) = (x+2z+6w, 3y+5w, 5x-6w)$

The domain seems to be $\mathbb{R}^4$, but how can I determine the codomain and image of a linear map? Also I would probably need to verity that $T(x,y,z,w)$ has the properties $T(u+v) = T(u) + T(v)$ and $T(\alpha u) = \alpha T(u)$ or is this true immediately from the matrix representation?

Comment: The $+6w$ should not be there in the first row, otherwise it's fine. The codomain is the space where $T$ maps to, including the image, this is now $\Bbb R^3$.

Answer (score 1):

We have $T: \mathbb R^4 \to \mathbb R^3$ and $T(x)=Ax.$ Yes, $T$ is linear.

It is easy to see that $A$ has rank $3.$  Thus $T( \mathbb R^4)= \mathbb R^3.$

Comment: The codomain would be $\Bbb R^3$ even if the rank was less.